# Request Mapping to a specific item in the list

Tags: spring

sorry i am new to spring boot and trying to learn, i have this code that when i run it will open a json request of my catalog items if i enter any url that is `localhost/catalog/(any userid)`. But i want to narrow it to 1 specific userid how can i do that? for example if i put l`ocalhost/catalog/friends` i will get the information for only friends and if i put `localhost/catalog/gameofthrones` i will get information for gameofthrones only and not the whole list

Code:

```
package com.poc.moviecatalog.controller;

import com.poc.moviecatalog.models.CatalogItem;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/catalog")
public class MovieController {

    @RequestMapping("/{userId}")
    public List<CatalogItem> getCatalog(@PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
       return Arrays.asList(
               new CatalogItem("friends", "test", 9),
               new CatalogItem("gameofthrones", "test2", 3)
       );
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you must add a @RequestParam to handle that. So you url will be like localhost/catalog/USERID?catalog=friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/catalog")
public class MovieController {
    private Map<String, CatalogItem> storage = new HashMap<String, CatalogItem>() {{
        storage.put("friends", new CatalogItem("friends", "test", 9));
        storage.put("gameofthrones", new CatalogItem("gameofthrones", "test2", 3));
    }};

    @GetMapping
    public Collection<CatalogItem> getAllCatalogs() {
        return storage.values();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{userId}")
    public CatalogItem getCatalog(@PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
        return storage.get(userId);
    }

}
```

I have initialized the map with all instances of CatalogItem. I store your `userId` as a key and instance as a value. I have defined two endpoints: *one for getting all objects* and *one to find just one object*.

Method `getAllCatalogs()` returns all objects in response. To call this method you can request `/catalog` path.

Method `getCatalog(String userId)` returns just one object in response by
your requested userId. You can get just one instance by request `/catalog/{userId}` path. In the method `getCatalog(String userId)` I just find an instance in the map by key (userId).

You can use another solution to store your objects (in-memory, database) instead of Map.

Comment: Thank you so much Oleg, just to point out there should be a semi colon after private Map<String, CatalogItem>

Comment: In this case, double-braced initialization is used. The semicolon is placed after the two closing brackets. But I do not advise you to use this way because it has some [disadvantages](https://www.baeldung.com/java-double-brace-initialization#disadvantages-of-using-double-braces).